# How to query simple CSS selectors on the Chrome Accessibility Tree of a webpage?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, accessibility

**Background**

The Chrome accessibility tree contains enough information that it should be possible to reconstruct a (possibly incomplete but usable) virtual DOM tree. For example, here's two log lines from [a test page](https://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/form-test.html), when viewing its tree in `chrome://accessibility`:

```
++++++ROLE_SYSTEM_PROGRESSBAR name='Your score is:' parent='ROLE_SYSTEM_GROUPING' window_class='Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND' value='91' OFFSCREEN FOCUSABLE display:inline-block tag:meter explicit-name:true valuetext:91 id:meter text-align:left currentValue=91 minimumValue=0 maximumValue=100 default_action='hacer clic en la superclase' action_name='clickAncestor' location=(521, 2570) size=(108, 22) index_in_parent=4 n_relations=1 n_characters=0 n_selections=0
++++++ROLE_SYSTEM_STATICTEXT name='new' parent='ROLE_SYSTEM_GROUPING' window_class='Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND' OFFSCREEN display:inline-block offset:0 background-color:rgb(153\,153\,0) color:rgb(200\,195\,188) font-family:Arial font-size:9pt language:es writing-mode:lr ia2_hypertext='new' default_action='hacer clic en la superclase' action_name='clickAncestor' location=(640, 2568) size=(41, 25) index_in_parent=5 n_relations=0 n_characters=3 n_selections=0
```

In particular, notice that the style information, the element tag name, and the element's id, etc. is available.

**My use case**

A desktop app needs to have access to the DOM tree of a Chrome webpage. This is to run basic CSS selectors and then to read the value of the selected element.
If it matters, I am focused on Windows.

**My understanding**

The [Chrome Accessibility APIs](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility/) are the official technique. But I did not find any example for how to run CSS selectors on top of this tree. I understand that there can never be a complete implementation. But for simple selectors, like `tagname`, `#id`, `[style^=""], tagname > tagname`, this would be very useful.

My current plan is to parse the entire accessibility tree, reconstruct the DOM using JSDOM, and then run the CSS selector on it. But it is a bit tedious and probably has a couple of edge cases that I am not yet aware of.

**Question**

Is there any clearer, more direct way to achieve my use case here?

Comment: Since the CSS selectors cannot be completely supported, why not convert the selector itself into another search criterion to search in the API? Maybe into a regex.

Comment: @Andy In my use case, the selectors are provided externally, so I cannot ask the external system to resend them as regexes. If you are suggesting that my system should input a selector and then automatically convert that to a regex, I think that's an even harder problem than constructing the DOM virtually.

Comment: I'd be inclined towards regex too, but that's because I am quite confident about regex. As an alternative approach, have you tried using AOM? I know it's not finalised, and is hidden behind a flag, but it might help you along, for example with a headless chromium instance or whatever. https://github.com/WICG/aom

Comment: I’m suggesting that you convert CSS selectors into regexes on runtime.